# ColdFusion client for Swagger OpenAPI spec

Tags: coldfusion, swagger, client, openapi, cfml

We have an OpenAPI (Swagger 2.0) specification for our API.  One of our customers uses ColdFusion and wants to have a native client SDK implemented in CFML.

It seems that Swagger Codegen does not actually support CFML/ColdFusion.  However, since OpenAPIs are so common now I thought there must be some way to generate a CFML library from an OpenAPI/Swagger 2.0 Spec.

Does anyone know how to do this?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ColdFusion can create and invoke any Java objects, so you can probably generate a Java package for the API using the Codegen and export it. Your customer then just needs to deploy the `.jar` on their server and call the methods via ColdFusion's [`createObject("java", ...)`](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-c-d/CreateObject.html).

Comment: Thanks @Alex - unfortunately my customer is not very technical and so this probably won't work for them.  Is there really no way to generate a native client from an OpenAPI?  How about from a SOAP?